# Yet another version of Mazur's lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, reference-request, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a normed vector space. [Mazur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%27s_lemma?wprov=sfti1), in its classic form, states that if a sequence $(x_{n})$ in $X$ converges weakly to $x_{0} \in X$, then there is a sequence $(y_{n})$ such that

$$y_{n} \in \mathrm{conv} \biggl( \bigcup_{i = n}^{N(n)} \{ x_{i} \} \biggr) \quad \text{for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}$}$$

and

$$y_{n} \to x_{0}  \quad \text{strongly}.$$

According to another version of the lemma, under the same assumption there is a sequence $(z_{n})$ such that

$$z_{n} \in \mathrm{conv} \biggl( \bigcup_{i = 1}^{n} \{ x_{i} \} \biggr) \quad \text{for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}$}$$
and
$$z_{n} \to x_{0}  \quad \text{strongly}.$$

This second version appears as Exercise 3.4 in Brezis' *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*.

**Question.**
Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Does there exist a sequence $(w_{n})$ such that

$$w_{n} \in \mathrm{conv} \biggl( \bigcup_{i = m}^{m+n} \{ x_{i} \} \biggr) \quad \text{for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}$}$$

and

$$w_{n} \to x_{0}  \quad \text{strongly}?$$

If, as I suspect, the answer is *yes*, can one then say a few words about the proof and/or provide a reference?

Comment: The third version follows from the second applied to $y_i=x_{m+i}$. The second version follows from Mazur's by passing to a subsequence.